# API to Mapping client printer to Windows Terminal server

Tags: windows, winapi, terminal-services

I am writing an utility to map the printer available on a local machine to the terminal server when the user uses RDS client. I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312135 which enables us to do it manually but i just want to get started with doing it through API. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Remote Desktop ActiveX Control, call IMsTscAx::AdvancedSettings to get advanced settings, then call [IMsTscAdvancedSettings::DisableRdpdr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381821%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using mstsc.exe to connect to a terminal server. I need to write some utility which will be invoked in the client side when user connects to terminal server and maps the local printer using mstsc. Should i need to use IMsTscAx::AdvancedSettings?

Comment: Since you don't have control on the client, do you have control on how the user would use mstsc (e.g. having them to run a preconfigurated rdp file)?